# AG - GRID render all in one column

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to use ag grid in a new angular 11 project, but the simplest example doesn't fit well, because show me the table in only one column.

[image]

I followed this guide, but the first time that you have to see the table, it goes wrong

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/getting-started/

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my English

Comment: Looks to me like you forgot to import the ag-grid styles into the styles.scss

Comment: thanks @Bertramp, you are right. I had to change the locations of the imports of css, that I have in the own component instead of styles.styl

Answer (score 0):

in certain circumstances npm will perform an "auto prune". This step ensures all expected dependencies are | present

```
npm install --save ag-grid-community ag-grid-angular
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

**please add your .css file link to your html page.
ag-grid.css & ag-theme-alpine.css files.**

Comment: Use the comment function